# Variable assignment inside AWS ssm does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, ssm

I am trying to run below command on AWS SSM:

```
Parameters = @{
           commands = @(
           "Write-Host userid is  $userID password $($password)"
           '$userID2 = $userID'
           '$password2 = $password'
           "Write-Host userid is  $userID2 password $($password2)"
       ) 
        }
```

First Write-Host statement prints the correct values of $userID and $password but after the assignment of the new variable, second `Write-Host` variable prints empty for both variables. Am I doing something wrong? I tried fetching the values of `$userID` and `$password` with double quotes as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same issue. Problem is that before sending the commands to EC2, AWS will replace the commands with all variable values and hence, we cannot reuse the variables inside the commands directly. This is the workaround I had to come up with:

```
$userID = 'testuser1'
$password = 'testpassword'
$userIdString = "`$userID2 = '$userID'"
$passwordString = "`$password2 = '$password'"

Parameters = @{
           commands = @(
           "Write-Host userid is  $userID password $($password)"
           "$userIdString"
           "$passwordString"
           "Write-Host userid is  $userID2 password $($password2)"
       ) 
        }
```

Now it prints the `$userID2` and `$password2` fine.